# How Do I Fix The Error Below to Run Simple Python Programs? Error In VSCode Terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am getting the error code below in Visual Studio Code Terminal when I try to run a simple "Hello World" python program. I previously had installed Anaconda and would like to continue now without it. I did a Windows Reset (with cloud installation) but I'm still getting this message. Visual Studio Code is finding the Python interpreter.

---

& : The term 'C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe' is
not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS Code cannot find your conda, since it is not in your PATH. You might add it to your PATH (by reinstalling or adding it in Windows settings) - or:

Check if you can change your Python interpreter to something VSCode can find (Ctrl + Shift + P, start typing "Python Select Interpreter" until you can choose it from the menu).

Comment: I installed Visual Studio Code and then Python per the online documentation. It is finding the interpreter (3.9.6). I don't want to install conda I want to fix it so that it is not looking for conda at all. Like it was never installed in the first place.

Comment: It still sounds that conda is at some point earlier installed in your system, and VSCode tries uses the conda environment but cannot find it.
Have a look at this for more information about VSCode environments:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments